# Problem with Solve (Lagrange multiplier)

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, maximum

I'm trying to solve a simple maximization problem, which I can easily solve by hand using the Lagrangian method.

**I want to maximize `UH` subject to `BC=0`.**

```
 UH[CH_, IH_] := CH^α (γH V1 + γH IH)^(1 - α)
BC[CH_, IH_] := CH + IH + ρ τ (γH V1 + γH IH) - YH

$Assumptions = CH > 0 && CH ∈ Reals && IH > 0 && IH ∈ Reals && V1 > 0 && V1 ∈ Reals && YH > 0 && YH ∈ Reals && α > 0 && α < 1 && α ∈ Reals && γH > 
1 && γH ∈ Reals && lambda ∈ Reals ;
```

Other threads recommend using [`Maximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html), but

```
Maximize[{UH[CH, IH], BC[CH, IH] == 0}, {CH, IH}]
```

does not return any result.

I have also tried to implement the *Lagrangian* with

```
L = UH[CH, IH] - lambda (BC[CH, IH])
Solve[{{D[L, CH] == 0, D[L, IH] == 0, D[L, lambda] == 0}, CH, IH}, lambda]
```

which returns the error message that this is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities.

I am probably overlooking something simple (I'm new to *Mathematica*), but I have now spent two hours on this simple problem and would thus really appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include minimal working example of your code and data in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: It's a typo, sorry. Removing it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Perhaps `Solve[{D[L, CH] == 0, D[L, IH] == 0, D[L, lambda] == 0}, {CH, IH, lambda}]`?

Comment: This gives me an expression for CH as a function of IH, and for lambda; but it does not solve correctly for CH and IH as a function of parameters.

Comment: In the constraints two parameters `ρ ,τ ` appear which aren't considered in the assumption!

Comment: If you change the solve command (Lagrangian) to `Solve[{ D[L, CH] == 0, D[L, IH] == 0, D[L, lambda] == 0, 
  BC[CH, IH] == 0}, {CH, IH , lambda}]` MMA evaluates  a result together with some  messages.

Comment: the problem has inequality constraints, too; are you interested in those too? because if you do then they should enter the Lagrangian, too.

Comment: For fixed (rational) values of $\alpha$ Maximize will give you a solution, but it doesn't manage to find a general solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lagrange multiplier method is just a way of expressing the requirement that the gradients of the target function and the constraint function are linearly dependent. Therefore, you can implement the method directly by requiring that the determinant of the Jacobian should vanish. Here I do this:

```
Solve[
 BC[CH, IH] == 0 && 
  Simplify[Det[D[{UH[CH, IH], BC[CH, IH]}, {{CH, IH}}]] == 0], {CH, IH}]

(*
==> {{CH -> V1 α + YH α, 
  IH -> -((-YH + V1 α + YH α + 
     V1 γH ρ τ)/(1 + γH ρ τ))}}
*)
```

The `D` operation acts on the vector of both functions, and therefore gives the Jacobian matrix. I combine this with the constraint equation and then solve for the two unknowns in one step. `Simplify` is inserted before doing `Solve` to apply the `$Assumptions` as early as possible to eliminate undesirable solutions.

The difference to the approach using `Maximize` is that this method doesn't actually verify whether it's a maximum. But that's precisely why the above code works even without specifying numerical values of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The constraints of the optimization problem are both equality constraints (`BC`) and inequality constraints (`CH>0` and `IH>0`). The Lagrangian for the maximization problem is defined as:

```
Lg[CH_, IH_, x_, y_, z_] := UH[CH, IH] - x BC[CH, IH] + y CH + z IH
```

the multiplier `x` is associated with the *equality* constraint while the multipliers `y` and `z` are associated with the non-negativity constraints on the variables `vars={CH,IH}`.

A full characterization of the solution should in principle consider the first order conditions `focs = Thread[D[Lg[CH, IH, x, y, z], {{CH, IH, x}}] == 0]` along with the complementary slackness constraints `cscs = Thread[{y, z} vars == 0]`, the original non-negativity constraints `oineqcs = Thread[vars > 0]` and the non-negativity of the multipliers of the inequality constraints `nnoineqcs = Thread[{y, z} >= 0]`.

Now, consider the fact that for the complementary slackness conditions to hold, the corresponding multipliers must equal `0` because of the strict non-negativity of the variables (`oineqcs`). Because of this, the critical points of the system can be obtained by solving the system of first order conditions (the derivatives of the Lagrangian wrt the variables `vars` and the equality constraint multiplier `x`):

```
Solve[
  (* enforce the complementary slackness requirement and solve *)
  focs /. Thread[{y, z} -> 0]//Simplify, Join[vars, {x}]
  (* simplify using assumptions about parameters *)
 ] // Simplify[#, Assumptions -> gineqs] &
```

> ```
> {{CH -> (V1 + YH) α, 
>     IH -> (YH - YH α - V1 (α + γH ρ τ))/(1 + γH ρ τ),
>     x -> -(-1 + α) γH (α/(γH - α γH))^α (1/(1 + γH ρ τ))^(1 - α)}, 
>    {CH -> Undefined, IH -> Undefined, x -> Undefined}, 
>    {CH -> Undefined, IH -> Undefined, x -> Undefined}}
> ```

The (first) solution above is a maximizer if the determinant of the bordered hessian of the Lagrangian is positive ie

```
(V1 + YH)^(-1 + α) α^(-1 + α) γH (-(((V1 + YH) (-1 + α) γH)/(1 + γH ρ τ)))^-α (1 + γH ρ τ) > 0
```

**Note**: The expression above is derived as `Det[bh]` where `bh` is the bordered hessian (derived below) and evaluated at the maximizer

```
 bh = With[{h = D[Lg[CH, IH, x, y, z], {{CH, IH}, 2}], c = D[BC[CH, IH], {{CH, IH}}]},
   Transpose[Prepend[Transpose[Prepend[h, c]], Prepend[c, 0]]]]
```

(also, `gineqs = {V1 > 0, YH > 0, α > 0, α < 1, γH > 1}` are the inequalities associated with the various parameters)